# how to display the text in a textbox of different function of the same class in python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to get the date from a calendar widget to get printed into a textbox. The calendar widget and the textbox are in the same class but the print function is in a different function. all in the same class.

here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import calendar
```

I have the printDate function to print the date

```
class Ui_Calendar(object):
  def printDate(self, qDate):
    date =('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(qDate.month(), qDate.day(), qDate.year()))
    self.setupUi.textedit.setText(date)
```

Here in this function i have the calendar widget and the textbox:

```
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
```

calendar widget:

```
    self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 392, 236))
    self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
    self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(self.printDate)
```

textbox:

```
    self.textedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,245,80,30))
    self.textedit.setObjectName("textedit")
```

I get the calendar widget to open when button clicked. I also can get the date printed on python shell but cannot the date on the textbox. As soon as i click the date on the calendar widget the program closes itself. i dont get any error msg.
I am new to programming and just started learning. Please help me

here is my whole code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Calendar(object):
  def printDate(self, qDate):
    date =('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(qDate.month(), qDate.day(), qDate.year()))
    #print(date)
    self.setupUi.textedit.setText(self.date.toStrings())

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(395, 310)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 392, 236))
    self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
    #self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(lambda dateval:print(dateval))
    self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(self.printDate)
    
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
    self.textedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,245,80,30))
    self.textedit.setObjectName("textedit")
    #self.printDate(self.label.setText(date))
    
    
    
    
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    #self.label.setText(_translate("Mainwindow","date"))


 if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_Calendar()
  ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  MainWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I just edited the code part so that it is more readable if that helps.

Comment: Post all the code you have, not individual chunks.

Comment: @S.Nick here i have edited again with my whole code at the end. everything works fine except the line  `self.setupUi.textedit.setText(self.date.toStrings())` inside the printDate functiom

Comment: there are too many things wrong with your code. Well someone just posted the answer, now you must get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer but create another class that inherits
from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Calendar(object):
#    def printDate(self, qDate):
#        date =('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(qDate.month(), qDate.day(), qDate.year()))
#        #print(date)
#        self.setupUi.textedit.setText(self.date.toStrings())

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(395, 310)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 392, 236))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        #self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(lambda dateval:print(dateval))
#        self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(self.printDate)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.textedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textedit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,245,80,30))
        self.textedit.setObjectName("textedit")
        #self.printDate(self.label.setText(date))
        
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        #self.label.setText(_translate("Mainwindow","date"))


class Calendar(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Calendar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(self.printDate)

    def printDate(self, qDate):
        date =('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(qDate.month(), qDate.day(), qDate.year()))
        
#        self.setupUi.textedit.setText(self.date.toStrings())
        self.textedit.setText(date)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_Calendar()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()

    w = Calendar()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]